# Trying to ban users based on Audit Log actions

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a bot and I'm making this automatic command where whenever someone deletes a channel, it bans them. Here's what I did:

```py
entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=dis.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
```

After that I did

```py
member = entry.user.name and member = discord.Member
```

and then

```py
member.ban(reason='Ask owner')
```

but when it runs the command it says

```py
missing 1 self in member.ban(reason="Ask owner')
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `discord.Member` instance to ban, not their username (as in `member = entry.user.name`) or the abstract base class (as in `member = discordMember`)

Something like this should work for you:

```py
entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=dis.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
member = entry.user  # this is the actual Discord user
if isinstance(member, discord.Member):  # check if the user is still on the server
    await member.ban(reason='Ask owner')
```

Comment: It doesnt do anything now doesnt even give any errors and it still doesnt ban someone

Comment: Have you made sure that the bot has the necessary permissions to ban the user? It needs to have the permission to ban members and the target cannot be higher in the server hierarchy than the bot

Comment: Yep it has administrator and ban members permission it doesnt give any errors or ban

Comment: Then try adding an `else: print(f'Not a valid member: {type(member)}')` for debugging purposes to the end of the code

Comment: still does not work: (

Comment: It has to either ban (and potentially error out) or print something - if neither happens, the code fails somewhere prior to this snippet

Comment: i made an elif and after that i put a pass and i put the code after it but it still doesnt work:(